# (Mac) Automatically run script on login

Tags: bash, macos, shell

Because of a small disk I've got an external USB-C SSD drive where I want to move some software projects I'm currently no working on.
To see the outsourced projects in my default projects directory in finder and terminal, I thought of Symlinking the external projects to my default folder. I tried using fswatch to detect changes and automatically Symlink new folders.

```
# watchExternalProjects.sh
fswatch -o /Volumes/SSD/Projects/ | xargs -n1 -I{} ./createSymlinks.sh
```

```
# createSymlinks.sh
cd ~/Projects && find -L . -name . -o -type d -prune -o -type l -exec rm {} +

ln -s /Volumes/SSD/Projects/* ~/Projects/ 2> /dev/null
```

This works, but now I want to automatically start this script on login. I've tried making an Automator App which calls the script and put it in the login items, but the watcher does not stay active but runs only once on login and further changes are not detected.
I've also tried setting up a Launch Agent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/Documents/Files/watchExternalProjects.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This seems not to work.

Any ideas?

### Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/user/Documents/Files/watchExternalProjects.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/user</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>user</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.user.loginscript.stdout</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.user.loginscript.stderr</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This seems to work, maybe the first one also did. But now I'm able to track it down to an "Operation not permitted" error logged in com.user.loginscript.stderr

Comment: I would recommend to ask this question also on Ask Different apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Don't you just need to background the task by adding `&` within watchExternalProjects.sh? I presume it kills the fswatch process once the parent process ends.

Comment: @bobdylan I've already tried that with Automator. Not sure how to do this in the Launch Agent.

Comment: Why not just set this up as a system service instead?

Comment: As far as i know there are those two approaches for writing system services on Mac, the Automator and the Launch Agent. The last one would be the equivalent to Linux systemctl, on Mac launchctl. Or do I miss something?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing? Is it running your script at all? I presume the watcher is some agent type thing which you want to run always - as opposed to run > exit? This is why I suggested back grounding / nohup'ing the command. If you want it to fire and exit then stick it in cron to run as often as you want.